# Update Python Package in Mamba vs. Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, command-line-interface, boto3, mamba

I am attempting to update a Python package in Mamba, specifically to a version of `boto3=1.26.63`.  I am trying to do so using the syntax

```
mamba update boto3=1.26.63
```

but receive an error stating:

> Encountered problems while solving: -nothing provides requested boto3 1.26.63**

Can someone please confirm the syntax for upgrading packages using Mamba?  I am familiar with how to do so using Conda, but I am attempting to build out a software development environment using Mamba and need to confirm the appropriate syntax...any assistance is most appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `conda-forge` channel? The `defaults` channel simply doesn't have that version. (Note that you should not use `conda-forge` channel with Anaconda **base** - there be dragons). Otherwise, that syntax works perfectly fine in `mamba` v1.1; though for `conda` it must be `conda install boto3=1.26.63`, i.e., you can't specify versions with `update` command.